# How to split a resultset in Java into chunks (500 rows each) without looping?

Tags: java, optimization, jdbc, sybase, resultset

I have a query which returns millions of records which are held in a result set. I have to process (insert/update) these records.  Instead of inserting all the record at once I would like to split the the resultset into chunks of 500 records each and store in an `ArrayList` or `Vector` and process these 500 records at a time.

How do I split the resultset into chunks & store in an `ArrayList` or `Vector`  without looping through the million records?

i found the answer , got to use CachedRowSet instead of resultset. and use set setPageSize

```
CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl(); 
crs.setPageSize(500); 
crs.execute(conHandle);
```

and then use

```
  while(crs.nextPage()) {

        collection obj = crs.toCollections();
 }
```

this would ensure that a we could process large data into smaller chunks

but i have a dought here how would the crs populate by passing a connection object where do mention the query string ??

Comment: "without looping"  Why?  Ignore for the moment what you are trying to do, and describe what you are trying to *achieve* by doing it without looping.  (I feel that will produce better answers.)

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your SQL dialect. For example, in PostgreSQL there are `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses for SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0;
```

You still will need some kind of loop to generate queries to fetch all millions of your records.

Comment: Sadly there's no standard compliant way to do this as far as I'm aware. MySql uses LIMIT <startpos>, <nr_entries>, with Oracle you have to include a ROWNUM clause in your where and so on :/

Comment: of course this does not split a 'resultset', it only attempts to divide the source data into ranges - and even that will fail unless a) the data is non-volatile between executions and b) there is an order by clause on a key used for the limit and offset

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch you data in the single query because you will not get the same result in multiple queries in multiuser environment.

If the client memory is the issue - bcp out the query result in file at the first and  split your file with something like unix split command.

You can parse your splited data file by file or bcp in in a working table and load data in the your ArrayList.